# Mysterious/Unknown IPs keep getting whitelisted by spamd

Tags: openbsd, pf, opensmtpd, spamd

I have an OpenBSD 7.1 mail server running OpenSMTPD with spamd.

I notice mysterious IP addresses in /var/log/maillog, such as:

```
smtp connected address=162.142.125.222 host=scanner-25.ch1.censys-scanner.com
```

These IPs keep getting whitelisted in the spamdb, which I don't want to happen.  Should they not talk to spamd first, rather than go straight to SMTPD?

My /etc/pf.conf reads:

```
emailserver = "192.168.7.5"
email = "{ smtp, imaps }"

set skip on lo

block all
block return    # block stateless traffic
pass            # establish keep-state

# By default, do not permit remote connections to X11
block return in on ! lo0 proto tcp to port 6000:6010

# Port build user does not need network
block return out log proto {tcp udp} user _pbuild

#pass in on egress proto tcp to any port smtp
pass in on egress proto tcp to any port submission

table <badhosts> persist file "/etc/badhosts"
table <sshguard> persist
table <spamd-white> persist
table <nospamd> persist file "/etc/mail/nospamd"

block in quick from <sshguard>
block in quick from <badhosts>
pass in log on egress proto tcp to any port smtp \
 divert-to 127.0.0.1 port spamd
pass in log on egress proto tcp from <nospamd> to any port smtp
pass in log on egress proto tcp from <spamd-white> to any port smtp
pass out log on egress proto tcp to any port smtp
pass log (to pflog1) proto tcp to $emailserver port $email
pass log (to pflog1) proto tcp from $emailserver to port smtp
```

I don't see why these IPs are getting whitelisted. They don't appear on the /etc/mail/nospamd whitelist.

Would it have something to do with the bottom two statements?

```
pass log (to pflog1) proto tcp to $emailserver port $email
pass log (to pflog1) proto tcp from $emailserver to port smtp
```

I was trying to add IPs of outgoing email to the whitelist, and added those two statements and created the pflog1 interface, after reading The Book of PF.